# Angular PatchValue problem with assigning value back to group

Tags: angular, angular5, formgroups

I met a problem where I tried to patchValue for one of control in a formgroup. And it never success.
I use Angular Material DatePicker with moment.js

Here is the HTML:

```
<form novalid  [formGroup]="desktopSearchForm">
      <div class="row-content" *ngIf="dateRange">
  <mat-form-field class="desktop-input">
    <input matInput [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="mobileFromDate" placeholder="From" formControlName="startDate" (focusout)="dateParse(desktopSearchForm.get('startDate'))" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="mobileFromDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #mobileFromDate></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the function I call in (focusout)

```
 this.desktopSearchForm = this.fb.group({
  classID: [''],
  startDate: [''], //This is the one I want to patch
  endDate: [''],
  transactionTypeID:['']
})

dateParse(control) {
if (control.value) {
  //control.value is a Moment.js Date object
  let group = <FormGroup>control.parent;
  let TheKey;
  Object.keys(group.controls).forEach(key => {
    let childControl = group.get(key);
    if (childControl === control) { // I found the Control I want to patch
      TheKey = key;                 
    }
  })
  group.patchValue({TheKey:control.value}) //I patch it here.
```

}

this function is for auto assign the correct date format back to the input field (image there are many datepickers with different name such as startDate,endDate etc). e.g I type 25111988 into the input box,while I focus out, the input value changes to '25/11/1988'.
But the problem is the control.value never patch to the key which is correctly show 'startDate'.

But If I change it to this and it works:

```
group.patchValue({startDate : control.value })
```

Also here is an another problem is:

if I put group.patchValue({startDate : control.value }) into :

```
Object.keys(group.controls).forEach(key => {
let childControl = group.get(key);
if (childControl === control) {
  group.patchValue({startDate : control.value })
}
```

})

Then it does not work.that's why I put this patch function outside of the forEach.

Need Help. Many Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `(focusout)="dateParse(mobileSearchForm.get('startDate'))"` be `(focusout)="dateParse(desktopSearchForm.get('startDate'))"`? (`desktopSearchForm` instead of `mobileSearchForm`)

Comment: Can you please create the stackblitz to check the issue.

Comment: @DanDumitru Sorry, I have edit the content, now the focusout is passing desktopSearchForm. It was a typo when I tried to copy to here.

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT Yes, I will create a stackblitz for this one later.

Comment: This question is much more easier to understand and good explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to bind dynamic keys where you assigning to **TheKey** and you can do like this way,

Only change is **{TheKey:control.value}** to **{[TheKey]:control.value}**

```
dateParse(control) {
if (control.value) {
  //control.value is a Moment.js Date object
  let group = <FormGroup>control.parent;
  let TheKey;
  Object.keys(group.controls).forEach(key => {
    let childControl = group.get(key);
    if (childControl === control) { // I found the Control I want to patch
      TheKey = key;                 
    }
  })
  group.patchValue({[TheKey]:control.value}) //I patch it here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!That made my day. But can you explain why the dynamic key is working??

Comment: In the new ES2015 standard for JavaScript (formerly called ES6), objects can be created with computed keys

Comment: In earlier JavaScript specifications (ES5 and below), the key in an object literal is always interpreted literally, as a string.

To use a "dynamic" key, you have to use bracket notation: